# Calling native APIs in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

In the documentation for Electron it [states](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process):

> In web pages, calling native GUI related APIs is not allowed

I don't understand what is meant by "native GUI related APIs". If I create a web page in Electron and add jQuery and then manipulate some element on the page, this works. I don't have to call back to the main process to perform UI updates. Does "native GUI related APIs" refer to something much more lower level (such as some API that is not based on Javascript)?

Comment: I believe from reading it that 'not allowed' is an overstatement, 'not recommended' would probably be closer. AFAICT the docs are suggesting that those resources are leaked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native Gui API's refers to desktop API such as Menu and Tray

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/menu.md
https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/tray/

i.e. API's which allow you to interact with the Desktop Environment.

e.g You will not be able to create a Tray application using Web Pages